# Define foreground color of a itextsharp table cell

Tags: c#, itext

I have a iTextSharp.text.Table and tried to change the foreground text color. But there is no method on the Cell object to define the color. Does anybody knows, where I can adjust the color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following

```
    var FontColour = new BaseColor(31, 73, 125);
    var MyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 11, FontColour );
    table.AddCell(new Paragraph("My Text", MyFont));
```

Comment: Yep.  Foreground text color is defined by the Font for the high-level text layout code.  When you start using a PdfContentByte directly, the font and color become separated, but not until then.

Answer (score 0):

LnDCobras answerworked well.

My final solution is the following:

```
Font font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 11, new Color(255, 0, 0));
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("my Text", font);
Cell cell = new Cell(chunk);

table.AddCell(cell);
```